# Drupal How to add java script to ctools modal popup

Tags: jquery, drupal, modal-dialog, drupal-ctools

I need to hide some element with some condition using jquery inside ctools modal popup in drupal after popup load. I used drupal_add_js but that not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ctools_ajax_command_attr('selector','attr','value')` to perform any kind of actions in popup.